# 'isOctave' or 'isMatlab' equivalent?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to write some code which, depending on user, might be run in Matlab or Octave.

One of the key things is the output of a video (using VideoWriter) in Matlab.

This apparently isn't supported in Octave, but I'd still like to be able to modify the final image in Octave.

Is there a quick way to determine whether a .m is being run in Matlab vs Octave?  Is there a quick way to flag one or the other?

Comment: I would use exist('VideoWriter')  command, in that way your code would automatically use VideoWriter in Octave when its implemented.

Comment: and, btw, there is the "old" video interface in GNU Octave: https://wiki.octave.org/Video_package

Comment: https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/How-to-Distinguish-Between-Octave-and-Matlab.html#How-to-Distinguish-Between-Octave-and-Matlab